# PPT VBA image's left and top are size-dependent?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to use VBA to control the location of images. I found that for images with different sizes if they are both aligned to the left side of the slide (I can see the automatic grid), they have very different values in the horizontal position. This is really weird. So I used `ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Left = 0` for each one of them and their left edge are not aligned.

[image] The 2 images have the same original size but I shrank one of them and they are partially overlapped here. Although their horizontal positions are both 0", none of them are aligned on the left edge of the slide. Themselves are not even aligned on the left side.

This is really hard to understand. I thought the left and top of an image are absolute regarding to a slide? Could someone explain why it acts like this and if there's any way to fix it? Thanks!

Edit: I also change the rotation with the size change of the images but that doesn't change the horizontal position, so I'm curious whether the horizontal position is not relative.

Comment: This could be an issue with the original graphics used, or with your code. But we have access to neither so _Idunno_

Answer (score -1):

Try ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(i).Left

When I paste it works for me, but for tables.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. Tchenically ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(i) is a shape object and that is of the same type as ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1). Your line gave the exact results I showed above.